# How is it possible to calculate a multidimensional interpolation on position (lat/long) and time data in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, cubic-spline

I would like to perform a multidimensional interpolation on my data. My data has the following structure: Time, Latitude, Longitude, Speed, Course.
At the moment I split the data into 4 separate time series, like: (Time, Latitude), (Time, Longitude) and so on. For each time series i am now calculating a cubic spline and linear interpolation. Afterwards i'm merging the calculated data, to one dataset.

However, I am afraid that due to a separate interpolation, some dependencies between the data will be ignored and the interpolation results will be worse than in a single multidimensional interpolation.

Therefore I would like to perform an additional multidimensional interpolation on the data. I would also like to calculate at least the multidimensional-linear and multidimensional-cubic interpolation. By entering a time point (e.g. x=23) I want to get the latitude, longitude, speed and course values.

Does anyone know some Python libraries that could be useful for my project? Big thank you in advance.

**Perhaps necessary addition to the question:** For me its unclear how i can create an interpolation where I only have to enter the timestamp to get the remaining data. In the example of scipy i have to enter A, B, C to get a value for D. But my question was whether it is possible to perform a interpolation, so i can enter A and get B, C, D.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html

Comment: Did you give a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata (2 min google search)? From what I get, you have all the tools available to perform this analysis on your own and quantify/qualify the differences between your two strategies. Anyways, where is your data ? your code? What are the data dependencies you are afraid of ? If there are known constraints, you may as well define your own interpolation model.

Comment: Of course, I found this library, too. But for me its unclear how i can create an interpolation where I only have to enter the timestamp to get the remaining data. In the example of scipy i have to enter A, B, C to get a value for D. But my question was whether it is possible to perform a interpolation, so i can enter A and get B, C, D.

Comment: Unrelated, but from a physical point of view interpolating lat-lan values is far from trivial. Close to the equator, a minute of lat or long give more or less same distance. But when you reach the 60° of latitude, a minute of lat gives half the distance of a minute of long. Numerical methods always give numerical results. Whether the results are physically relevant is **the** question.

Comment: But my tracks only has a length of about 15km, so you can probably neglect the influence of the earth's curvature again, can't you? I think the influence of the Earth's curvature would be bigger (and therefore more relevant) if the track would extend over several degrees on earth.